# Dynamic cells vs static?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I want to create a table view with text fields in the cells that are editable to the user. Like filling out a form. I want the text fields to have placeholders etc, and when tapping on the cell I want the keyboard to show to edit the text fields. I also would like the table view to be in a tab view. I wanted to use storyboards, and wanted to know the best project to pick for iPhone and iPad, and wether to use static cells or prototype cells as the best choice for my app? Look forward to your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Static cells would be easier you can create IBOutlets from your cell directly in you view controller class. The down side is they are not dynamic (big surprise) you can hide and show views in the cell. But you can not hide and show whole cells or sections. If your form fields are fixed then use static but if the form need to change you need to use dynamic cells. If you use dynamic cells you need to subclass UITableViewCell to create your IBOutlets.